# Adding a scrollView to make other views present on the screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a problem concerning the scrollView. 
In my xml code I have a bunch of TextViews and under these TextViews I have a button. Because I have too many TextViews, the button does not appear on the screen. Therefore, I added a layout containing all of these TextViews and I put this layout inside a scrollView. However, it is still does not work. Do you have any idea why?

Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_of_people_present"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20sp"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout_textViews"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text1"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text2"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text3"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text4"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text5"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text6"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text7"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text8"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text9"
                    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_a_member"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Add a member" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output where you see only the scrollable textViews but the button has disappeared:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add your image of your output

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You mean if you scroll your layout than Button was not scroll ??

Comment: I do not want the button to be scrolled actually. At the beginning I wanted to add on my screen x number of textViews and under the textViews a button. However, when I add too many textviews, the button disappear from the screen. So I added a Scrollviews for all the textViews. The scrollView is working (I have a scrollbar for the textviews) but the button has still disappeared.
Am I clear?

Comment: Yeah but because it is inside a relativeLayout, the button is not under the textViews :(

Comment: Sorry but which answer do you talk about?

Comment: Sorry for that now see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this xml will help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_of_people_present"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20sp"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_textViews"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text1"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text2"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text3"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text4"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text5"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text6"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text7"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text7"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Text7"
                        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
                        android:textSize="35sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_a_member"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Add a member" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is change in this xml file can you tell me ?

Comment: I just delete the relative layout, and just use relative layout

Comment: The thing is I need the relativeLayout. Indeed, as you see in my xml code, I add a toolbar that I want to put at the bottom of the screen (as you can see on the picture)